Python PyQt6 can't set exact pixel size, can't set absolute positions either
I'm trying to write a simple custom widget with exact size and position, as I will have several widgets side by side and absolute positioning is a must as I will use background images as well.
import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, num):
        super().__init__()

        self.num = str(num)
        self.setFixedSize(70, 70)

        label = QLabel(self.num)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        label.size = QSize(50, 50)
        label.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
 
        label.move(100, 100)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50, 50)
    def heightForWidth(self, width):
        return width


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    w = QWidget()
    w.setWindowTitle("w1")
    w.show()
    w.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")
    w.setGeometry(600, 1500, 300, 300)
    l = QVBoxLayout(w)
    l.setSpacing(0)

    l.addWidget(MyWidget(1))
    l.addWidget(MyWidget(2))

    sys.exit(app.exec())

The output:

The issues I have with the code above are:

MyWIdget.label seems to be set always to 20 pixels less on X and Y than its parent, MyWidget, so I have self.setFixedSize(70, 70). If I set self.setFixedSize(50, 50), MyWidget.label will be painted with 30x30 pixels.
Both light blue squares (MyWidget.label) are 48x48 pixels, not 50x50.
label.move(100, 100) does nothing.
The target here is to just have MyWidget with 50x50, and the label inside occupy all of MyWidget space, i.e. for it to be 50x50 pixels as well.

Any ideas on what is causing the issues above?

Setting fixed geometries is almost always discouraged, especially for widgets that contain text. There are two common issues in trying to do that: 1. it does not consider the font metrics (nor the actual font eventually set by the user); 2. it does not consider user configuration, including font scaling and DPI settings. Even ignoring the above, the purpose of layout managers, as the name suggests, is to manage the layout: calling move() (similar to setGeometry()) is therefore pointless. As setting the size attribute, which is also wrong in principle, since it's not a "setter".

I understand the need to put widgets at specific coordinates based on an image "background", but you have to consider that doing that is not as immediate as one would think (the font/DPI aspects above can have lots of unexpected consequences), and even assuming you are really aware about those aspects, that also means that you cannot just add those widgets to a layout manager, since what you actually want is to explicitly manage the layout, which is the exact opposite of their purpose.

The default layout margin is usually 11px. Thus, 11px + 11px + 48px gives 70px. Adding the line layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) and changing to self.setFixedSize(50, 50) will fix the sizing problem. You can also remove  the label.size and label.move lines and the sizeHint and heightForWidth methods. Setting a fixed size is sufficient. (Of course, none of the this will help with any font/DPI problems - but that's a separate issue).
